# Removing a disk from an Ubuntu mdadm RAID marks the array as inactive, instead of degraded

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, software-raid, mdadm

I'm setting up a mdadm raid 1 array on Ubuntu 14.10 under VirtualBox.
Everything works fine:

```
The raid 1 is set up with /dev/sdc1 and /dev/sdd1:
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid1 sdd1[2] sdc1[0]
      1045952 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

However, if I unplug one of the disks, say /dev/sdb, here's what I get:

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : inactive sdc1[2](S)
      1046016 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
```

This is not what I expected... I was expecting a degraded Raid 1 array, not an inactive array.
What am I doing wrong?

My mdadm.conf lists the array as:

```
# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md/0  level=raid1 num-devices=2 devices=/dev/sdc1,/dev/sdd1 metadata=1.2 UUID=ffa72d1e:a18e2f76:2d336ad8:5f01069b name=ubuntu:0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, thanks archbishop for setting me on the right track.
The trick is to stop the array (even though it is already inactive), which then allows the assemble/run to complete.

```
sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md0
sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 --run
```

And just to call out the obvious, the final step is to remount the array.

```
sudo mount -a
```

Answer (score 1):

mdadm(8) says:

> If mdadm can not find all of the components for an array, it will
>   assemble it but not activate it unless --run or --scan is given.  To
>   preserve this behaviour even with --scan, add --no-degraded.  Note
>   that "all of the components" means as many as were present the last
>   time the array was running as recorded in the superblock.  If the
>   array was already degraded, and the missing device is not a new
>   problem, it will still be assembled.  It is only newly missing devices
>   that cause the array not to be started.

If you just want to get the mirror running, try

```
mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 --run
```

This should get you up in degraded mode.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work...

    09:03:12 relja@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 --run
    09:03:30 relja@ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/mdstat
    Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6]      [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
    md0 : inactive sdc1[2](S)
          1046016 blocks super 1.2

    unused devices: <none>